# Debianized way to add -O2 to CFLAGS without using CDBS in Qt project

Tags: qt, g++, debian, packaging

What is the standard mechanism to deliver compiler optimization level information in debianized source using qmake without using cdbs?

For example, if DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS doesn't have noopt defined, -O2 should go into CFLAGS. Everytime I try to specify CFLAGS myself in debian/rules, it gets overwritten by Makefile that was generated by qmake system.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have control over the qmake `.pro` file? If yes, you could use qmake's `$$()` or `$()` syntax to use the value of the environment variable either during Makefile generation or evaluation.

Another (more involved) option might be to set the `QMAKESPEC` environment variable to make qmake use another base configuration.